# SSH: remote variable

Tags: bash, ssh, variable

I want to run a complex script via ssh

```
#!/bin/sh

ARRAY1=(
server1s
server123
server12
server14
server13
)


for i in ${ARRAY1[@]};do ssh  $i "
    case \$HOSTNAME in 

server1.domain.com)
echo try1
  ;;
server12.domain.com)
echo try12
  ;;
*)
echo try123
  ;;
esac
```

The problem is ssh read my internal hostname variable
and return try123,is possible to read the internal variable
of remote site?
I have tried \$VARIABLE and $VARIABLE but result is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\$HOSTNAME` is the correct way to escape the variable in this case.

However, that variable often contains the hostname (non-fqdn), or may not be populated. You should rather use the command `hostname -f` to get your server FQDN.

I don't know how will look like your final script, but connecting to `server1` then check if this server is `server1` may be some kind of useless (out of security purpose).

You could write some scripts, for instance `script1.sh` containing

```
echo "$HOSTNAME / $(hostname -f)"
```

then

```
for i in ${ARRAY1[@]};do
    case $i in
      server1) ssh $i < script1.sh
      ;;
      server2) ssh $i < script2.sh
      ;;
      *) ssh $i < script_${i}.sh
    esac
 done
```

**EDIT:** As stated in comments, OpenBSD shipped version of `hostname` doesn't understand `-f` option. The default behaviour is to display FQDN.

Comment: Usually use this solution calling external script,i prefer one script wich make all,but if no possible..i will use this,so i accept this solution

Comment: Nit pick: `$ hostname -f` - `hostname: unknown option -- f` - `usage: hostname [-s] [name-of-host]`.  `$ uname -rsv` - `OpenBSD 5.7 GENERIC.MP#992`.

Comment: @elbarna It's up to you :) I said that just in case you didn't know it was possible, but I don't want to force you to use one way or another, this is really up to you :)

Comment: @lcd047 sorry, the FreeBSD version accept `-f` option, but I didn't test OpenBSD... I'll edit my answer, thanks.